# JWPlayer reading from a php script with redirect

Tags: jwplayer

I am trying to use a php script as the 'file' end point for JWPlayer,  the PHP script generates a TempURL from Rackspace then redircts to the generated URL.  I was hoping that JWPlayer would follow the redirect.

Is it possible to have JWPlaer to follow redirects?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just add this line to your player setup code:

```
'type':'mp4',
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan, sorry I forgot to update this question.  The problem was my server was redirecting from http to https so the link was being broken.  I updated my server conf. and it is working perfectly now.